# How can I find the port using local ip address by openstacksdk?

Tags: openstack, openstack-neutron

When I use the openstacksdk, I tried use `conn.network.find_port()` method to find the port, but I only knows the local_ip address, but the `conn.network.find_port()` params requires the id or the name.

In my openstack cloud, I list the ports:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

You see, I only knows the fixed_ips' ip_address, but how can I get the port by openstacksdk?